# Android : Null Pointer Exception on GPS application

Tags: android, gps, nullpointerexception, location

I try to create an application for my studies which is a tracking sportif.

When I send a new localisation, my application crash due to this error :

```
03-18 18:44:34.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 18:44:34.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 18:44:34.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839)
03-18 18:44:34.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): at fr.polytech.trackersportif.GPSData.onLocationChanged(GPSData.java:28)
03-18 18:44:34.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:255)
03-18 18:44:34.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:184)
03-18 18:44:34.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:200)
03-18 18:44:34.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-18 18:44:34.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-18 18:44:34.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-18 18:44:34.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 18:44:34.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-18 18:44:34.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-18 18:44:34.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-18 18:44:34.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My mainActivity is :

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationListener = new GPSData();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, locationListener);
```

And to finish my class (GPSData) is :

```
public class GPSData extends Activity implements LocationListener{

 TextView textLong, textLat;



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.page_accueil);  //page_acceuil is the layout where are the two textview that I want set text  
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

     textLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     textLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    textLong.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
    textLat.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));        
}
```

I try diferent things since two day but I have this error again and again.

Can you help me please?

Comment: where are you testing your app?

Comment: The class GPSData should not extend Activity.  GPSData should be a private class inside the mainActivity that implements LocationListener.

Answer (score 0):

You can't test your Geo-location based app in the emulator without specifying a lat long coordinates to it using `telnet` and the `geo fix lat coordinate long coordinate` command.

Comment: The BIG glaring mistake here is the incorrect assumption that LocationListener is invoking an Activity.......

Answer (score 0):

You have to put GPSData into the mainactivity. You only can access to (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); in MainActivity

And MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

Answer (score 0):

Calling `new` is not the proper way to start an `Activity`.  Your `NullPointerException` is most likely being thrown on the line:

```
textLong.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
```

This is because creating a new `Activity` by calling `new` does not trigger the `onCreate` method.  Therefore, your `GPSData` class never has a view set because `setContentView` isn't being called.  That means calling `findViewById` with one of your own view ids will always return `null`.

Instead of setting up your `LocationListener` from your `MainActivity`, I recommend doing it in your `GPSData` class.  To do so, you'd have to make the following changes:

MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, GPSData.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

GPSData:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.page_accueil);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, this);
}
```

You should be able to leave the rest of your `GPSData` class alone.  Only change the `onCreate` method to match this one.

This is all assuming you actually want `GPSData` to be a separate `Activity` like your code is setup.  If you don't want it to be a separate `Activity` then I'd recommend making `GPSData` a private inner class and make it not extend `Activity` like BrianPlummer suggested.  In that case, your `GPSData` class would look like this:

```
private class GPSData implements LocationListener {

    TextView textLong;
    TextView textLat;

    public GPSData() {
        textLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {    
        textLong.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
        textLat.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think, I do a mistake when I separate Activity.

But I don't understand how is it possible to make GPSData in a private inner class. Can you explain with more details?

Comment: Then you might want to follow the advice at the bottom of the answer to make `GPSData` not extend `Activity` and make it an inner class.

Comment: OK but if I remove "extend Activity", is it possible to set text of a Textview?

Comment: If it is an inner class of your main activity then yes.

Comment: So I need to put my class GPSData in the MainActivity?

Comment: That is one way to fix this, yes.

Comment: do I need to remove the method on create in my GPSData?

Comment: Editing my post to include the new code for your `GPSData` class.  In the future, after getting some information from the people on StackOverflow, try and work through your problem again instead of asking for every minor detail.  We're all here to help, not write everybody's code.

Comment: thank you for your code but I had already find the solution but i hadn't take time to write that in my post. Thank you for your time, it's my first application and I didn't know what is a inner class but with some search I found and I understood what is it